# Would like to know how to capitalize first letter and get a error if you don't capitalize

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to figure out how to code the capitalize() into this under the `name=input("What is your first name? ")` and get a `error message` as shown in the 8th line if you don't contain the first capitalized letter of the name. Thanks in advance if anyone's willing to help.

```
  def exampleName():
     valid_characters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

  while True:
        name=input("What is your first name? ")
        # while not name.capitalize()

        if all(char in valid_characters for char in name):
              break
        print("\nI'm sorry " + name + ", only capitalized first letter and letters.")
        name=input("Please re-enter your name: ")
     print("\nThank you, " + name + ".")
  exampleName()
```

Comment: Why dont just convert the name to capital weather user enter capitalized or small?

Comment: to check only first letter you can do: if (name == name.capitalize()):

Comment: @Paul Rooney, I want them to put in whatever they like for the first string but I want to give them the error if they do not put in the first capitalized letter of their name.

Comment: @thisisjayjaymehta, what do you mean? And how would I do that and include the error message as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def example_name():
    name = input("What is your first name? ")
    while True:
        if name.istitle() and name.isalpha():
            break

        print(f"\nI'm sorry {name}, only capitalized first letter and letters.")

        name = input("Please re-enter your name: ")
    print("\nThank you, " + name + ".")


example_name()
```

To make it more simple you can do the following:

```
def example_name():
    name = input("What is your first name? ")
    while not name.istitle() or not name.isalpha():
        print(f"\nI'm sorry {name}, only capitalized first letter and letters.")

        name = input("Please re-enter your name: ")
    print(f"\nThank you, {name}.")


example_name()
```

What you do is to run your while loop untill there is a valid 'name'

Comment: Hey, thanks, this worked! Can I ask why ```name.istitle()``` and not ```name.capitalize()```?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. istitle checks if string (name) has the first character as uppercase. That is what you looking for, having first char as capital and return True or False. capitalize() function converts first char to uppercase.

Comment: Is it possible to do a capitalize one?

Comment: capitalize() will convert first char to capital. For instance 'ben'.capitalize() will return 'Ben', but it will not validate if the first 'ben' has the first character in upper case.

Comment: @Ben why even check? It'd be shorter code to just force the first letter to be capitalized.

Comment: @BruceWayne, because that's exactly what I was asking for and wanted to know a solution to get capitalize() working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple if statement to check if the first character is upper or lower case.
A possible edge case might be if there is white space, in which case you should find a way to check for it or ignore it in the input.

```
def enterCapName():

string = input("What is your name?\n")


while string[0].islower() == True:
    print("You need to capitalize your name", string, "\n")

    string = input("What is your name?\n")

if string[0].isupper() == True:
    print("You followed instructions.\nThank you", string)
```

This won't work if you're trying to see if multiple words are capitalized or if there is whitespace as the first value of the string, but you can test against the whitespace, much like you can test for islower or isupper and you can probably loop through the words in the input and check if all first values are upper. I would recommend `string.split()` and iterate through the words/names.

example:

```
name = " Art magi"
name.split()
#['Art', 'magi']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require the input to be capitalized, you can just do:

```
name = input("What is your first name? ").capitalize()
print(name)
```

So regardless if they type `ben` or `Ben`, `name` will be `Ben`.

> What is your first name? ben
> Ben
>
> What is your first name? Ben
> Ben